# eclipse papyrus look and feel for uml diagrams

Tags: eclipse, look-and-feel, papyrus

I have been playing with Eclipse's PApyrus Tool. It seems a cool tool: I created some UML component and class diagrams, everything seems ok. I however have on my screen a clean diagram [image: a clean diagram]!,

but get no nice look and feel like the one presented on papyrus home page[image: one presented on papyrus home page]!

How can I get my diagram to the presented cool look and feel?

Maybe a stupid question, but haven't been able to figure it out and I am fiddling & googling for a while...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your default CSS theme is not set or it is a black/white one.

To check which theme is currently active go to:

`Settings -> Papyrus -> CSS Theme`

Having `Papyrus Theme` selected with Papyrus `0.10.2` in Eclipse Kepler produces colored diagrams for me similar to your second example.